# Link a button in a XIB to a viewcontroller in a Storboard Email

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib, xcode-storyboard

I have a XIB viewcontroller with a button in it. I also have a storboard viewcontroller. I would like to know if there is a way to link a button from the xib view controller to the storyboard viewcontroller.

The error

2014-03-30 16:44:30.597 HandMandy[2364:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c1b795 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101725991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c9fe69 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010130703a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c17700 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001005d11b8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1131
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001005d2bb2 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 138
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010038781d -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 42
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100386b1a -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 454
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100397aab -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3092
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100397f1e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001003882be _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 618
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104977bb6 _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010497767d PurpleEventCallback + 35
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b9d819     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 41
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b9d5ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101bc6ab3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101bc5f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001003864bd -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100388043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    20  HandyMandy                          0x0000000100000ea3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001032755fd start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Word to the wise: don't leave your email address all over the internet at your age.

Comment: It's okay cuz its not even my real name but it is my email address.

Comment: Also this site is used best when the answers to questions are provided on the site. Do not ask people to email you. If the answer is too long for the answer box this site is probably the wrong place to be.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your storyboard click the view controller you want to present.

Then under the Identity Inspector [image], in storyboard ID, give your view controller an ID.

Then in the IBAction in your XIB view controller for your button do:

```
//Create an instance of the storyboard
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
//Create the view controller
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
//Present the view controller
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will present the view controller modally.

Comment: I get a message saying Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: What exactly does the SIGABRT say in the log window?

Comment: Ill post it into my post

Comment: I posted it into my question.

Comment: Does the sigabrt error happen without the above code?

Comment: No it happens with the above code